# In O-notation, does the memory taken by a list increase linearly with list size?

Tags: python, big-o

My book says "As the length of a list grows, the number of references stored in it grows linearly, but memory needed to store a reference to the list's contents stays the same." What does this mean? Is the space complexity O(n) or O(1) as the list size increases?

Comment: @MarkRansom Why would it be unfortunate that `list` is not a *linked* list? It is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), and Python is not the only language which uses the word "list" to mean not only linked lists, e.g. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1), [Dart](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html), AppleScript, R. I'd say it's more unfortunate that C++ and Lisp call linked lists just "lists".

Comment: @kaya3 I'd argue that the term "array" is much more widespread for that data structure and would have made a better choice, as there's less chance for confusion.

Comment: @MarkRansom But an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure)) is a fixed-length data structure; it's unfortunate that languages such as Javascript use this name for things that are actually lists. The term [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) is used for the data structure which uses an array to implement the list data type, but Python naming this type `list` is consistent with the rest of Python's collections like `dict` and `set`, which take the names of the data types rather than the data structure (hashtables) used to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists, the space complexity grows linearly as the number of elements increases. But the variable holds a reference to a list, and the reference is of fixed size, so changes in the actual list data will not cause a change in the reference size.

This relationship is like the data allocated on the heap and the corresponding pointer in c.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a list `l = [1,2]` then create another reference to it `l2 = l`.  `l2` shares the data `[1,2]`.  You can see that by changing `l2[0] = 3` then `l[0]` is now also `3`:

```
l = [1,2]
l2 = l
l2[0] = 3
print(l)
[3,2]
```

The references `l` and `l2` are of O(1) space which means for sufficiently large n it requires no more than `k` space per reference.  The data itself O(n) so for sufficiently large `n` it requires no more than n * k1 + k0 space.  k, k0, k1 are constants.

Comment: right. so if I append more elements to list l the space complexity is O(n)?

Comment: Correct.  For sufficiently large number of elements n, you need no more than n * k1 + k0 space where k1 and k0 are constants.